# Where to find Cpanel python app console logs?

Tags: django, cpanel, passenger, phusion

i'm trying to deploy Django app in cpanel 
after configuring settings and installing requirements i have this error
[image]

i want the location of log file to check the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to see via cPanel -> File Admin -> /home/user/app/stderr.log -> select watch up in the right corner, this is the standard output for Python server. Hope helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, you can put the following code in htaccess:

```
PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
```